# Apache and Mysql using Ubuntu mate

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I'm new to Ubuntu. I tried to run a .php file and connect it to a database. Everything is on-set. I already imported the database in **phpMyAdmin** but every time I access my database,it returns an error

> This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this
>   request. HTTP ERROR 500

Turns out, it seems like my database isn't running at all. In Windows I just open the **XAMPP** and click Apache and **MySQL** buttons. While in Ubuntu,
I have no idea on how to start or run **MySQL** and Apache. I already tried running commands on the terminal but it won't help. Someone has already installed it on this computer, I just don't how to run it and what web-server platform is this running.

How do I do it and how would I know that my database is running and accessible?

Comment: Add this to the top of your PHP page to help with debugging.  
`<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
`

Comment: And after, paste your output into your question.

Comment: It doesn't show anything at all. No display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to connect your database and access database via command line.

```
mysql -u [username] -p
```

you can replace `[username]` with your real username of mysql like `root`

it will prompt for password so you are type yours like `root`

prompt will say

```
mysql>
```

now you need to list all databases to see is database exists or not

```
show databases;
```

it will list down all databases. you may verify is your exists or not

then you can select database by

```
use databasename;
```

and then run

```
show tables;
```

it will show all tables.

so you can verify that mysql working, database exists and tables are there or not.

Comment: I tried these commands and indeed it showed that my database is intact.

Comment: OK now you may try to get connected in php file. and show errors or enable errors

Answer (score 0):

Use this command it will start the database is you have it

```
 systemctl mysql start
```

This should do the trick you need to have mysql database or maria db installed

Check by running this command in terminal after the first one

```
 mysql
```

And you can also add argument like host and login

```
mysql  -h (your host default is localhost) -u (user default is root) -p (password default is none)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your files access level

```
sudo chmod -R 777 "location of your file"
```